# How should I access onclick href using python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

How can I access onclick href using python? The html code for the website I want to scrap and my code are as follows:

HTML code:

```
 < a class="" onclick href="http://moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=394" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1505961565869_139"> 
     <span class="instancename" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1505961565869_138">Lecture 1- 4 Introduction and programing languages evaluation criteria
         <span class="accesshide"> File</span>
     </span>
 </a>
```

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
links={"http://moodle/course/view.php?id=764",}

for link in links:
    html=requests.get(link)
    raw= html.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(raw,"lxml")
```

Comment: The answer depends what libraries you are using

Comment: selenium and bs4. @cricket_007

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question?

Comment: just search them using xPath

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element by the id `yui_3_17_2_1_1505961565869_139`, and then use selenium to `click()` it

Comment: The site will have many such onclick href and id does not follow a fix pattern. How can I get all the ids then?

Comment: You can find all elements with `a` tag and click on those